# error : duplicate value for attr/style with config ' '

Tags: android, gradle

After upgrading Android Studio to the latest version, it keeps on giving me this error and I can't run my code at all!!

Here's the error

```
Android resource compilation failed
Output:  C:\Users\Khairy\Desktop\Patient App\android-patient-app\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1072: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/style' with config ''.
C:\Users\Khairy\Desktop\Patient App\android-patient-app\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1072: error: resource previously defined here.

Command: C:\Users\Khairy\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar\dd46b604dd8462c5ee8864f277da747e\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        C:\Users\Khairy\Desktop\Patient App\android-patient-app\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        C:\Users\Khairy\Desktop\Patient App\android-patient-app\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Answer (score 0):

> error: duplicate value for resource '`attr/style`' with config ''

Check `values.xml` or `styles.xml` to see if there is any duplicate entries-strings. (called `attr/style` maybe)

You can also try removing `intermediates` or `build` directory then doing clean-rebuild project and then it should work as expected.